# Storing DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID in sql server table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-security

We're using stored procedures to restrict the access of some of our database users. They need access to specific parts of the database (not just tables/views, but also specific rows), and the sproc should check if the user is allowed to see the table rows he's requesting.

To store the authorization rules, we're planning to use a table `dbo.AuthRules` like that:

```
|ID|UserId  |AccessFrom  |AccessTo    | ...
===============================================
| 1|       1| 01.01.2013 | 31.12.2013 | ...
| 2|       2| 31.05.2012 | 31.12.2015 | ...
```

The stored procedure would then query that table to check if the current user has access to the requested data. **To make it clear:** We cannot just use `GRANT PERMISSION` because we need fine-grained access rules down to the rows in the DB.

We're not sure about the `UserId` column. The best solution would be some kind of foreign key to the system view `sys.database_principals`, but there are no foreign keys to views.

- Should we just store the `principal_id` column of `sys.database_principals`, without any constraint?
- Would it be better to store the `name` column instead of `principal_id`?
- Are there other options to store a reference to the DB user?

Comment: The `sid` is more stable than either name/ID

Comment: But the `sid` is only set for Windows auth users, right? So in case of SQL Server authenticated users, we'd still have to use `ID` or `name`.

Comment: no, every login gets a SID. Windows users get a SID that matches their windows SID, whereas SQL logins get a separately generated one. See [Principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181127.aspx): "**Every** principal has a security identifier (SID)." (My emphasis) before it then goes on to describe the different types of principals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Should we just store the principal_id column of sys.database_principals, without any constraint?

A: If you are evaluating only a constraint-based solution, you don't really have any choice. However, if you are willing to write a trigger, that would be the way to at least 'virtually' create constraint. Otherwise you would have to reference system `sysowners` table and this isn't possible without some hacking.

Q: Would it be better to store the name column instead of principal_id?

A: To answer that you have to ask the what-if question. What if principal_id changes? What if name changes? What about updates/deletes? I would always rather have an id-based solution.

Q: Are there other options to store a reference to the DB user?

A: As stated in answer#1, I don't think there are any possibilities except creating a trigger...

Answer (score 1):

Consider this design method.

```
USE "master";

-- Create our test logins (don't forget to tidy these up later!)
CREATE LOGIN "batman"
  WITH PASSWORD = N''
     , CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF
     , CHECK_POLICY = OFF;

CREATE LOGIN "robin"
  WITH PASSWORD = N''
     , CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF
     , CHECK_POLICY = OFF;

USE "playdb";

-- Create the corresponding users
CREATE USER "batman"
  FOR LOGIN "batman";

CREATE USER "robin"
  FOR LOGIN "robin";

-- Grant them some select permissions
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'batman';
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'robin';

-- Create our "user access" table
DECLARE @users table (
   username    sysname NOT NULL
 , access_from date    NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01' -- Deliberately not allowing nulls and setting the widest possible value range
 , access_to   date    NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31' --   this will make our queries so much easier!
);

-- Give one user full permissions
INSERT INTO @users (username)
  VALUES ('batman');

-- Limit what this chappy can see
INSERT INTO @users (username, access_from, access_to)
  VALUES ('robin', '2011-01-01', '2012-01-01');

-- Example data table
DECLARE @data table (
  date_field date NOT NULL
);
-- ...with example data
INSERT INTO @data (date_field)
  VALUES ('2010-01-01')
       , ('2011-01-01')
       , ('2012-01-01')
       , ('2012-01-01')
       , ('2013-01-01')
       , ('2014-01-01');

-- Let's mimic our full access user
SETUSER 'batman';

SELECT System_User As current_username
     , *
FROM   @data As data
WHERE  EXISTS ( -- Limit the records to only those this user is allowed to see
         SELECT *
         FROM   @users
         WHERE  username = System_User
         AND    data.date_field >= access_from
         AND    data.date_field <  access_to
       );

SETUSER; -- Reset user

-- Imitate the chap with restricted access
SETUSER 'robin';

-- Exacty same query as before
SELECT System_User As current_username
     , *
FROM   @data As data
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   @users
         WHERE  username = System_User
         AND    data.date_field >= access_from
         AND    data.date_field <  access_to
       );
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a sample implementation of what I meant, but I'm not sure about what's your point. You're storing the user's `name` property, which is less stable than his `ID` or his `sid`..

Comment: The username is transparent and portable (new ID/SIDS if you have to recreate users on a new server e.g. dev/qa/live).It can be a SQL username, windows authed username or windows auth group name which means it is very flexible too!